# Ngrep through router

Tags: nmap

I want to know if it's possible to capture net traffic through a router.

In detail:

I'm connected to a local router, which is connected to another router, i want to capture the traffic in the neighborhood of that second router, something like:

me--router1--router2

And i want to know if it's possible to capture traffic from the computers connected to "router2" using NGREP. I can easily unplug router1, connect myself directly to router2 and achieve what i want, but i wanna know if it's possible to do it somehow bypassing router1 using any flag in NMAP.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Obviously i know router1's ip in router2 network, router1 gateway ip, etc.

Comment: nmap is a port scanner, not a packet capture tool...

Comment: Sorry!! I mean ngrep! Didn't know what was i thinking :s

Answer (score 1):

ngrep can only capture packets which are seen by the network card in the sniffing system. Packets between router1 and router2 do not get send to the local network card. So you cannot ngrep these remote packets.